# json_encode response "" to android app

Tags: php, android, json

I did a lot of program with cominicate between php script to android app via json.
I met with strange problem today.I can send variable each other between php script to my latest android app.But in same program with diffirent php scrpit android can not see variables that are passed via json_encode.I checked php scrpit used print_r to see all variables got values.
[image: used print_r($response to see variables got values]

here my php script that try cominicate with android

```
function retrieveTenColimist($sortForWhat,$period){

$response = array();
global $db;
global $stmt;
$response["tencolumnist"]= array();
$period=$period*10;
if($sortForWhat=="favorite"){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM yazar Order By FavoriSayisi DESC LIMIT ?,10");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $period, PDO::PARAM_INT);

}
else if($sortForWhat=="read"){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM yazar Order By OkunmaSayisi DESC LIMIT ?,10");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $period, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
else{

    return "";
}
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $tenColumnist= array();
    $tenColumnist["columnistName"] = $row["AdiSoyadi"]; 
    $tenColumnist["writingUrl"] = $row["UrlAdresi"];
    $tenColumnist["newspaper"] = $row["Gazetesi"];      
    $tenColumnist["headline"] = $row["Baslik"];    
    $tenColumnist["readedNumber"] = $row["OkunmaSayisi"]; 
    $tenColumnist["favoriteNumber"] = $row["FavoriSayisi"];
    $tenColumnist["columnistImgUrl"] = $row["YazarImg"];

    array_push($response["tencolumnist"], $tenColumnist); 



    }
    $response["sucesss"]=1;
     echo json_encode($response);
```

}

I checked android app which can enter correctly to if or else if condition

here is in android result
[image: Android see only ""]

***Read before comment***

In same application with different php script They can send variables to each other so  that there should be no problem in android part

Note:If I slash `//array_push($response["tencolumnist"], $tenColumnist);` result like this

> {"tencolumnist":[],"sucesss":1}

and android part can see that

***Latest Update:
I have remote server upluaded to my php script there and code run perfectly but in localhost it does not work. I use wamp server with latest php version. is something depraceted?***

Comment: Can it be the output from `return "";` ???  Change it to    `return "test";` and check.

Comment: nope,deleted and nothing changed.Moreover during test,if i slash like this //array_push($response["tencolumnist"], $tenColumnist); got json like this {"tencolumnist":[],"sucesss":1} and android can see that.

Comment: What about trying a single dimensional array??@Beyaz

Comment: I tried multidimensional array before and succed and this is same code could not understand to problem

Comment: Your `Json_encode` giving proper output. Something else is the issue.

Comment: json_encode give blank space if i run in web browser. if i test with print_r it gives follewing pictre above.Moreover read my edited question. I tested it remote server and it work what can be problem?

Comment: How do you access your local server? 127.0.0.1?? localhost?? or with an IP?@beyaz

Comment: android:http://10.0.2.2 webrowser:localhost

Comment: what is the exact problem you facing? Are you having encoding problems to utf-8?